# PHP header appends to old url

Tags: php, redirect, get, header

I am trying to implement a feature where after a button is clicked, the server redirects the user to a new webpage with some variables in the url. I am running into a bug where the header function keeps appending to my existing url instead of refreshing it. EX:

```
http://localhost/455Project/messaging.php/new_message.php/?ssn=
```

messaging.php contains a button which when clicked redirects to new_message.php with a ssn attribute.

```
var_dump($_GET);
$temp = $_GET['patient'];
if(isset($_GET['new_message'])) {
$url = "new_message.php/?ssn=" . $temp;
header("Location: " . $url);
die();
}
```

The current url has the attribute which I want to get passed to the next. The var_dump has the correct value. I have also tried using `"/455Project/new_message.php/?ssn="` which solves the url appending but in either instance the `$temp` variable doesn't append the proper value.

EDIT: I have a dropdown that produces the url like this echo "

```
 `href='messaging.php/?patient=$patient_ssn_row[0]'>$name_row[0]  $name_row[1]'</a>";`
```

This corresponds to a dropdown with data and the user selects one of the options.

Comment: You've already solved the problem where the new URL gets appended to the old one. There are other possible solutions to that, but what you have seems fine. Leaving all those details in here obscures the real problem that you're having; you might consider editing down your question to focus on that.

Comment: What does the `var_dump` output? That seems very important in solving this, because your code looks fine, assuming that there really is a `patient` key in `$_GET`.

Comment: So the var_dump spits out a string of 9 numbers representing a ssn. I added an edit to the post, would this be the issue?

Comment: `$_GET` is not going to be just a string of 9 numbers. What *exactly* do you see from that? Looks like it should be okay from the URL, but much happens in between those two things.